# How to employ internal maven repo to generate a maven project Skeleton

Tags: java, maven, maven-repository

I normally use this mvn command to generate a maven project skeleton:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app
```

The thing is that maven goes maven official repo (repo.maven.apache.org) for artifacts downloading. It failed if I tried to do this from behind the company's firewall. The company does have a maven repo mirror site, but I don't know how to re-direct maven to use that one rather than the official maven repo site.

Is there a configure change / walk around in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the repository in the settings.xml.

If your company has a repository, they maybe already have a standard settings.xml.